# Creating graph from quadratic formula with domain [-5,5]

Tags: python, python-3.x

Deleted the main while loop due to formatting 
 a,b,c are taken from the user to obtain d

```
    if d < 0:
      print ("This equation has no real solution")
      break
    elif d == 0:
      x1 = (-b+math.sqrt(d))/2*a
      print ("This equation has one solutions: ", x1)
      break
    else:
      x1 = -b+math.sqrt(d)/2*a
      x2 = -b-math.sqrt(d)/2*a
      print ("This equation has two solutions: ", x1, " or", x2)
      break
  #for each x in xs
```

stuck around here
       #Prepare domain of graph
    x_0 = -5.0
    x_1 = +5.0
    n = 100

```
   #nested while loop

while x <= x_1:
   xs.append(x)


    #quadratic equation to append            
    y = a*x*x + b * x + c

     ys.append(y)
     x += dx
             # Graph the function
             # prepare the domain for the function we graph

     xs = pylab.linspace(x_0, x_1, n)
     pylab.plot(xs, ys, "bo-")
     pylab.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get the most out of the site it is important to ask good questions. A guide to asking questions is at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do you have an actual question?

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by using linspace for xs you get a np.array object, then you can rely on broadcasting to make the ys in the standard idiom of pylab/numpy

```
import pylab

# prepare the domain for the function we graph
x_0 = -5.0; x_1 = +5.0; n = 100
xs = pylab.linspace(x_0, x_1, n)
#print('xs: ',type(xs))

# quadratic equation 
def Quad(x, a = 1, b = 0, c = 0):  # def providing default values for a, b, c          
    return a*x*x + b * x + c

ys = Quad(xs) # since xs <class 'numpy.ndarray'> broadcasting magic is invoked
#print('ys: ',type(ys))

# Graph the function
pylab.plot(xs, ys, "bo-")
pylab.show()
```